# Не работают импорты в модуле __init__.py, якобы нет импортируемого модуля

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, модули

Учусь писать телеграм-бота, использую библиотеку aiogram. При попытке импорта в `__init__.py` модуль `client.py` пишет следующее:

File "C:\Users\Димон\Desktop\telegram-bot\bot\bot.py", line 3, in

```
from handlers import client, admin, other
```

File "C:\Users\Димон\Desktop\telegram-bot\bot\handlers_*init*_.py", line 1, in

```
import client
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'client'

При этом, у моего друга никаких проблем не возникло, хотя файлы у меня называются и находятся там же, где и у него.

Иерархия файлов выглядит так:

[image: иерархия]

Comment: Смотря что там `__init__.py` у вас. Если только импорты, то уберите их вообще, можно пустой файл оставить. Если они действительно нужны, делайте там относительный импорт, например `import .client` или абсолютный от пакета через `import handlers.client`

Comment: Дело не в расположении и наименовании, а в способе импорта. Импорт внутри пакета (между файлами пакета, у вас handlers - пакет) должен быть или через `import .имя_модуля` (относительный импорт) или `import имя_пакета.имя_модуля` (абсолютный импорт).

Comment: Без импортов действительно всё работает исправно, но почему у моего друга не возникло ошибки?

Comment: Разные версии Python

Comment: Ну откуда мне знать, может другие импорты были, или вообще `__init__.py` не было. Тут весь проект нужно видеть вместе с содержимым файлов, а не только структуру. Версии Python тоже имеют значения, но я думаю вряд ли у вас версии типа 3.5 или ниже. В новых версиях (типа 3.6-3.10) особых изменений в способе импорта не было, более старые - надо смотреть.

Comment: @insolor, нужна помощь. С `__init__` я всё понял, но теперь он ругается на другие импорты, пробовал импортировать всеми известными мне способами, но возникает ошибка, будто нужного модуля просто нет. Могу я скинуть ссылку на архив с этими файлами? Вы посмотрите, и скажите что у меня не так.

Comment: @insolor
Просто убедиться, что Вы прочтете

Comment: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pg8KHl8eplM5gfNaGciZNXq_vqzQJdBa/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Дмитрий пишет ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bot_telegram'`, чтобы такой импорт работал, нужно чтобы bot_telegram было запущено как пакет (а не запущен отдельный файл из этой папки), нужно запускать не через `python bot.py`, а через `python -m bot_telegram.bot` (это аналогично импорту этого модуля). Но в итоге циклический импорт будет. Вообще в идеале вложенные модули не должны ничего знать о вышестоящих.

Answer (score -1):

в файле `__init__.py` пропишите слудующее

```
from .client import dp
from .admin import dp
from .other import dp

__all__ = ['dp']
```

Comment: Три таких импорта нет смысла делать, каждый импорт у вас перезатирает результат предыдыщего импорта